# pick bitmap from android picker intent

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bitmap, android-bitmap

I'm trying to pick bitmap (.bmp) file using android picker, I use mimeType for this. However bitmaps files are dimmed and I cannot pick them. I try to use different extensions in setting type in intent like "image/bmp", "image/com.microsoft.bmp", "image/bitmap" without success.

One way is working - using "image/*" but it also allows other files that it shouldn't be allowed

my code:

```
chooseFile.type = ALLOWED_MIME_TYPES
chooseFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
chooseFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, availableMimeTypes)
chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Pick file")
startActivityForResult(chooseFile, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE)

*Mime types class*
const val docMimeType = "application/msword"
const val docxMimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
const val txtMimeType = "text/plain"
const val odtMimeType = "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text"
const val pdfMimeType = "application/pdf"
const val jpgMimeType = "image/jpg"
const val jpegMimeType = "image/jpeg"
const val bmpMimeType = "image/bmp"
const val bmpMimeType2 = "image/com.microsoft.bmp"
const val pngMimeType = "image/png"
const val heicMimeType = "image/heic"

const val ALLOWED_MIME_TYPES = "application/msword|application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document|" +
        "image/bmp|image/com.microsoft.bmp|text/plain|application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text|application/pdf|image/jpg|image/jpeg|image/heic"

val availableMimeTypes = arrayOf(
        docMimeType,
        docxMimeType,
        txtMimeType,
        odtMimeType,
        pdfMimeType,
        jpgMimeType,
        jpegMimeType,
        bmpMimeType,
        bmpMimeType2,
        pngMimeType,
        heicMimeType
)
```

Comment: Mime type:
image/bmp, image/x-bmp, image/x-bitmap, image/x-xbitmap, image/x-win-bitmap, image/x-windows-bmp, image/ms-bmp, image/x-ms-bmp, application/bmp, application/x-bmp, application/x-win-bitmap,

Comment: https://filext.com/file-extension/BMP

Comment: On my Android test device only "image/x-ms-bmp" worked.